# d3 zoom listener does not take into account programmatic zoom

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Before all, I can make the zoom behaviour work when attached to a "zoom" event (with the mouse for example).
AND I can programmatically zoom (triggered by an update in a document for example).

But if I have a zoom event, -->THEN programmatic zoom<--, then zoom event again, the second zoom event restarts from the position of the SVG drawing at the end of the previous mouse "zoom" event.

It is annoyingly discarding  what happened during the programmatic zoom.

"zoom" event:

```
const zoomed = () => select("g").attr("transform", event.transform);

svg
  .call(
    zoom()
      .extent([[0, 0], [600, 600]])
      .scaleExtent([0.1, 5000])
      .clickDistance(10)
      .on("zoom", zoomed)
  )
```

programmatic zoom:

```
let transform = zoomTransform(select("g").node());
let t = zoomIdentity
  .translate(transform.x + 1000, transform.y + 1000)
  .scale(transform.k);
select("g").attr("transform", t);
```

Help much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the transform on your zoom function, like so

```
svg.transition().duration(300).call(zoomFunc.transform, d3.zoomIdentity.translate(0, 0).scale(1));
```

where `zoomFunc` would be something like that

```
var zoomFunc = d3.zoom()
    .extent([[0, 0], [600, 600]])
    .scaleExtent([0.1, 5000])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

svg.call(zoomFunc)
```

I also made a demo [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/py5kfm97/1/).

Comment: Works perfectly !!!!.. Thanks sir, I probably would not have found it on my own ! Much obliged..